# How to Configure yiibooster

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

thanks for reading, i am wondering how to install

> YiiBooster

, do i need to install

> YiiBootstrap

first ? 
I want to install it by hand , is it enough to extract it to extensions folder and than configure the `main.php` or is there something i am missing ?

Also how can i make this point to the right path

```
'booster' => array(
'class' => 'path.alias.to.booster.components.Booster',
          ),
```

Comment: `'class' => 'protected/components/Booster',`

Comment: do i need to install bootstrap before, and do i need to unpack bootstrap in components ? or can i unpack it under protected ?

Comment: You can unpack anywhere, but it's better to unpack to components dir.

Comment: sory, i meant do i need to unpack bootstrap before i get booster ?

Comment: I found no requirements for Bootstrap to be installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to install bootstrap. Yiibooster includes all bootstrap files it needs. Just download Yiibooster, unpack to the extension folder and add the below to your main config file,

```
'booster' => array(
        'class' => 'ext.yiibooster.components.Bootstrap',
        'responsiveCss' => true,
        ),
```

Then add the following in the preload section of the config,

```
'booster',
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// uncomment the following to define a path alias
// Yii::setPathOfAlias('local','path/to/local-folder');
Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap', dirname(__FILE__).'/../extensions/bootstrap');

// preloading 'log' component
'preload'=>array('log','bootstrap'),

// application components
'components'=>array(
//
'bootstrap' => array(
        'class' => 'bootstrap.components.Booster',
        'responsiveCss' => true,
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename folder name **yiibooster-4.0.1** to **yiibooster**

**Step 1:**

```
'preload' => array(
   'booster',
),
```

**Step 2:**

```
'booster' => array(
'class' => 'ext.yiibooster.components.Booster', 
'responsiveCss' => true, 
),
```

**Note:** Booster this Class name

```
//Use view file

<?php
$this->widget('booster.widgets.TbExtendedGridView',
    array(
        'filter' => $model,
        'fixedHeader' => true,
        'type' => 'striped bordered',
        'headerOffset' => 40,
        // 40px is the height of the main navigation at bootstrap
        'dataProvider' =>$model->search(),
        'template' => "{items}",
        'columns' => array(
                'id',
                'firstname',
                'lastname',
                'age',
                'address',
                'email',
            ),
    )
);
?>
```